# rsync exit values

Tags: python, bash

I read in rsync manual that rsync return exit values in the range 0 - 35.
I tried to captured the output of rsync using the following code:

```
import subprocess, time, os, sys
cmd = ["rsync", "-avuxz", "/etc/passwd" ,"/tmp1/"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in p.stdout:
    print line.rstrip()
```

using the program above, i captured the following output from rsync:

```
rsync: mkdir "/tmp1" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

My questions:
- Is the rsync output is only as text (as above)?
- How can i distinguish between Success (code 0) and the error?
  (is it correct to assume: in case of Success the length of p.stdout will be zero and
  anything else is a failure?)

Comment: `stdout,err=p.communicate()` might help.

Comment: Given that you're running rsync with verbose flag, on success there will always be some output on stdout.  The exit code is not the same as the output to stdout/stderr.  See chepner's answer below to see the exit code.  I wouldn't rely on specific codes; anything non-zero is a failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the return code of the `Popen` object's process via the [`returncode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) attribute. If its value is `None`, the process hasn't completed yet; check again later.

For example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Dumb way to wait for the process to complete
while p.returncode is None:
    os.sleep(1)
if p.returncode:
    print "Error, rsync exited with non-zero status"
else:
    print "Success, rsync exited with zero status"
```

Comment: Is 'returncode' something like parsing on the 'stdout' string that is with 'Popen' captured?

Comment: No. The return code of a process is completely independent of any output the process produces on either standard output or standard error. In `bash`, you would see the return code of the most recently completed process in the `$?` parameter.

Comment: Maybe [`p.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead of pausing for 1 second?